# Query based on data from previous query within same while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a new query based on data from the previous.
however the second $_row overwrites the first, and I need data from both queries in 1 scope. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
$_query = "SELECT * FROM t_forum";

$_topics = $_PDO ->query($_query);


if ($_topics ->rowCount() > 0)
{
while($_row = $_topics -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{



    $_user_id = $_row['d_op']; //data to make new query 

    $_gebruiker = $_PDO ->query("SELECT * FROM t_users WHERE d_user_id =                  '$_user_id'");


        while ($_row = $_gebruiker -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


    //only data from second query
    }}
```

Comment: You can apply joins

Comment: You are naming the variable the same name.. maybe `$_row2 =` although you shouldnt use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

**USE LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT * FROM t_forum F LEFT JOIN t_users U ON F.d_op = U.d_user_id
```

From this query you will get data from both tables

Answer (score 0):

you can use join operation in mysql.you will get the result.

```
select * from t_forum as a 
join t_users as b 
on a.d_op=b.d_op
```

Answer (score 0):

you can join the two queries in one:

```
select * from t_users, t_forum where t_forum.d_op= t_users.d_user_id
```

Comment: All answers did the trick but I'm using this one as it made the most sense to me, thank you all